Why would nvmlDeviceGetCount return 0 devices, if I have a usable GPU?
I'm invoking nvmlDeviceGetCount() on a system with 2 GPUs, and it returns a device count of 0 GPUs - with no error. Why would it say that?
Additional information:

CUDA version: 12.6.68 (and bundled driver)
... in which a macro defines nvmlDeviceGetCount to be nvmlDeviceGetCount_v2.
nvidia-smi lists these two GPUs, and I am able to run CUDA kernels on them
OS: Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur
Kernel: Linux 6.6.13


Which version of the function are you using? The documentation describes something completely consistent with your output if it turns out you are using the v1 version.

@talonmies: nvmlDeviceGetCount_v2().
